# Changing snackbar typeface in androidx

Tags: android, androidx, android-snackbar

Before migrating to androidx, I used this code to change the typeface of snackbar text:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(main_Coordinator, "No Connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                View view = snackbar.getView();
                TextView textView = view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                textView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Shabnam.ttf"));
```

But after migrating to androidx I'm getting error for snackbar_text id `android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text` it says `Cannot resolve symbol design`.

And also I am using the new design library `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`

Any help?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just refer to the new design library like this -

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(main_Coordinator, "No Connection", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
            View view = snackbar.getView();
            TextView textView = view.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text);
            textView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Shabnam.ttf"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text`.

You've migrated to AndroidX, which means the library is different now. So the `R` that you're referencing needs to come from the new library instead of the old one.